# How do I get only uploads to show on the subscriptions panel on the homepage?

Tags: youtube

On the old layout it was easy, there was a checkbox. Now the only way I can see to do it is to do it individually for every subscription. There has to be an easier way.

Comment: Wish I had the rep to put a respectable bounty here - I was going to post just this question.  There should be an intuitive way to somehow filter out all the "commented on" updates and such noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a link that works :D

http://www.youtube.com/my_subscriptions?feature=mhum&dm=0

lengthening body because short answer is short.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why I made this Chrome extension: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/only-show-uploads-for-you/mcabnfpanhpiokkpgafhkmpcjlcnlmjj

If you're like me, clicking through hundreds of subscriptions is not fun and going to a different link to just see what I was seeing before is less than optimal.

Unfortunately only for Chrome now.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Chrome extension that will default the home page to subscriptions and uploads only: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-default-to-subscr/lglhfcembnpbdigiepeafgllldfaelpf